# Saving data that is in a table efficiently and also is easy to retrieve and echo back out

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Information**

I currently have a table which image is below,[image: table image]

**Problem**

I have made this table using `ul` & `li`
Here is the code

http://jsfiddle.net/8j2qe/1/

**Question**

What would be the best way of storing the data in the image and easily displaying it?

Keeping in mind that each column can only have 1 entry.

Thank you! And any questions will be answered ASAP!

**EDIT**

Sorry, I dont think I was clear enough in my initial question. What I am asking is, what is the best way to store and then display this type of data. I want to DISPLAY data from my database to show like it would in the image.

Should I have a column in my database for each column on the table, then say either A,B,C or D depending on what column it is in but then how would I display it using PHP in my code provided?

Im struggling to find a good way of explaining this, I am sorry.

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean by "storing the data in the image". You want to replace the table with an image? You want to generate the table instead of writing all cells by hand?

Comment: What do you want? A form design? A query?

Comment: A 2D array would be sufficient for this. If what you are looking for is a data structure.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I have updated the question, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: You must have at least a basic idea of how to implement this. Read up about database design if you have no clue how to effectivelly store this kind of data in a database. If you know how your database is going to look like, you can write your code to display this in a table/list structure from there.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I have never needed to implement something like this, and wouldn't know where to begin, hence I'm asking a question here. Do you have any more detailed advice on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: For interacting with the database, you can use php's mysqli. [This tutorial](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) might be of some help. I would recommend prepared queries. For database design. Google "database normalization". Get a basic sense of what that means and how you should design a database on that. Don't go completely blind on that though. There are cases where you should go with common sense instead of normalizing the heck out of everything. For the 'table' above, you probably want the 'place' of the checkmark for each 'number' in one database column.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I already know how to interact with a database therefore didn't ask about it, but thanks. For your actual reply to my question I think Basm.Egy ( the guy who submitted an answer ) has explained a much better way of doing it. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the data in form like

```
{
"0": [5,4,8],
"1": [2,3],
..
}
```

where object key refer to row index, and array values refer to index of checked column, you can easily generate this object in javascript by looping through each 'ul' element saving it's index as row index then get index of 'li' element that's checked & push it in array.

Then you serialize it back to server as json, save that json in DB.

Getting it back in php, you will loop through each row printing 'ul' element , then loop to print 'li' element, ex:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    echo '<ul>';

      //printing 18 column as u have in image
      for ($j=0; $j < 18; $j++) {      
         if ( in_array($j, $data[$i]) ) {
             echo '<li>CHECKED</li>';
         }else{
             echo '<li></li>';
         }
      }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

i think that's better than having table in db for each table u have.

finally providing context will greatly help in making a better answer, for ex: how table is generated , it's use, ...

Comment: This is perfect, Thank you for putting time into submitting an actual answer!